# Smooth scrolling in the shadow DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom, polymer, shadow-dom

I am working on a web app made with Web Components using Polymer. Each component has many child components each one with its own shadow DOM.

I am specifically working on a section with a big form with many fields, some of them outside the viewport. When I try to submit the form, a validation function is called. The validation function is tweaked so that it does not only return a boolean but sets an array with the invalid components called 'invalidElements'.

Then I can call focus on the first invalid element so that when I click submit the element focuses and comes into the viewport.

```
    invalidElements[0].focus()
```

The thing is that I would like to smoothly scroll to the invalid field. I can't use "scroll-behavior: smooth" because all ids are hidden under many shadow DOM's of parent components.

Even if I can get the id from invalidElement[0] ...

```
    invalidElement[0].id
```

... I can't access it after. I mean, I could, but it would imply to crawl the website entering every shadowDOM. Given the big size of the form, with it's many fields this would not be performant.

How could I then smooth scroll to the focused element?

Comment: I do not understand why you have code wrapped in an element `<i>invalidElements[0].focus()</i>`  Please provide the actual code and some way to illustrate your issue here (where it does not work)

Comment: It wasn't intended to be wrapped, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you like to scroll to element with out visiting any other controls.Then using Javascript you can achieve as below,

```
invalidElement.scrollIntoView({ block: "center", inline: "center"});
```

If you want to scroll to element slowly by visiting all the elements(smooth scroll), you can use below snippet.

```
invalidElement.scrollIntoView({ block: "center", inline: "center", behavior: "smooth" });
```

Comment: It works, thank you ;) I thought that scroll into view would only take an ID and this was a problem because it was hidden in the shadow DOM. But I was wrong...